# Power Sum Recursive Algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion

I'm working on an algorithm where we're given two inputs, a total amount, and a power value. We must find the total number of unique combinations of numbers to the power parameter that sum up to the total amount.

For example:
Given amount = 10 and power = 2, there is only one unique solution:
(1^2) + (3^2) = 10

(Problem comes from here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-power-sum)

Here's my algorithm thus far:

```
def count_unique_combos(total, candidate, power)
  return -1 if total < 0 || candidate > total # this means impossible to continue
  return 1 if total == 0 # arrived at our goal
  num_ways = 0

  # all the ways to get the total amount, if we use candidate ** power
  with_candidate = count_unique_combos(total - candidate ** power, candidate + 1, power)
  num_ways += with_candidate if with_candidate != -1


  # all the ways to get the total amount without using the candidate.
  without_candidate = count_unique_combos(total, candidate + 1, power)
  num_ways += without_candidate if without_candidate != -1

  num_ways
end
```

Here's what I'm confused about. I've read a lot about the recursive algorithm's leap of faith, where you assume that you have the function working for N-1 inputs, and you just need to make it work for input size N and put in the correct base cases.

The bases cases seem reasonable to me, as does the recursive relationship (get all unique combos with this number, get all of them without this number).

However, my output is incorrect. For amount = 10 and power = 2, my resulting value is zero. Does anyone know where I'm not approaching this logically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with swapping your base cases

```
  return 1 if total == 0 # arrived at our goal
  return -1 if total < 0 || candidate > total # this means impossible to continue
```

when `total == 0` any candidate you pass in (since you only ever increment candidate) is going to be `candidate > total` and you'll break out with a -1 before you check if you've reached your positive base case.

When you swap them (using tadman's test cases, for ease of comparison)

```
count_unique_combos(10, 1, 2)
# => 1
count_unique_combos(100, 1, 2)
# => 3
count_unique_combos(100, 1, 3)
# => 1
```

Comment: @Sunny Also, might I suggest using a default argument value for `candidate` so you don't have to pass 1 every time on the initial method call.

Comment: Hey @Eli --do you mind expanding on why its a bad idea to pass in 1 for initial method call? Thanks!

Comment: Passing 1 every time seems unnecessarily repetitive. Isn't that what default parameters are for?

Answer (score 1):

When you're talking about sets of numbers, especially when it pertains to permutations and/or combinations, it's a lot easier to lean on the core Ruby functions like [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
def power_sum(total, power)
  set = (1..total).to_a

  (1..set.length).flat_map do |size|
    set.combination(size).to_a
  end.select do |numbers|
    numbers.inject(0) { |s, n| s + n ** power } == total
  end
end
```

Then based on the test cases:

```
power_sum(10, 2)
# => [[1, 3]]

power_sum(100, 2)
# => [[10], [6, 8], [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]]

power_sum(100, 3)
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

If you only care about how many, call `.length` on the end.

A recursive approach is possible here, but the way you're tackling it doesn't seem to handle the combinations properly. You'll need to have two different recursive method that works with N-sized subsets.